# Getting "Illegal Instruction" error when trying to install cloudflared on a fresh Raspberry Pi install

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, dns-over-https

I am following the guide here for 32bit raspberry pi: https://bendews.com/posts/implement-dns-over-https/

At the very first step after "cloudflared -v" here I get an "illegal instruction" error and I can't proceed.

```
wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/VdrWdbjqyF/cloudflared-stable-linux-arm.tgz
tar -xvzf cloudflared-stable-linux-arm.tgz
sudo cp ./cloudflared /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cloudflared
cloudflared -v
```

This is on a fresh install of raspbian on a raspberry pi 1 B+ with all the necessary updates. I have re-formatted and started from the beginning twice now so I'm curious if anyone knows what is incorrect here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you need to use a fork of cloudflared specifically designed for pi zero/A etc for this to work from here:

https://hobin.ca/cloudflared/

just `wget` the latest deb release and install it with `dpkg`.